# Ui Automator takeScreenshot

Tags: android, ui-automation

I was trying to take a screenshot during the UI automation test, so here is the part of my code

```
Uidevice mDevice = Uidevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

mDevice.pressHome();

mDevice.takeScreenshot(new File("/root/sdcard/Pictures/test.png"));
```

I can run the test without error,but the screenshot didn't take after the testing,is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you have Storage permission? also please check your path I think it should be /sdcard/Pictures/test.png

Comment: yeah permission is ok,let me try the path,thank you.

Comment: are you running on rooted device? you need both READ and WRITE permissions

Comment: I remove the root and it worked,thank you~~